# Parse a log file into json object

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, logging, fs

I have log file named `request.log` this is the content of the log file

```
[2022-06-30T09:56:40.146Z] ### POST https://test.csdf/auth/send_otp  
    
 {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "User-Agent": "testing",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
[2022-06-30T09:56:40.668Z] ### POST https://test.csdf/auth/login  
    
 {
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "User-Agent": "testing",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  }
}
```

how can I parse the log file and transform it into array json object like this

```
[
  {
     "method": "POST",
     "url": "https://test.co/otp"
  },
  {
     "method": "POST",
     "url": "https://test.co/login"
  }
]
```

Comment: How are you generating this logs ??

Comment: Neither `https://test.co/otp` nor `https://test.co/login` are actually anywhere to be found in your sample data. So do you actually want to _manipulate_ those URLs from the log file ... or just pay a little more attention when asking?

Comment: If you want the URLs as they are - then just split this into individual lines and loop over them; check if a line starts with `[`, and if so, extract method & URL, if not, skip it and process the next one ...

Comment: @NS23 I actually have this http request function, and I put `fs.createWriteStream()` in there to log the request payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run some kind of script to convert them to JSON. In javascript/nodejs you could do something like this:

```js
const logFileContents = `[2022-06-30T09:56:40.146Z] ### POST https://test.csdf/auth/send_otp  
    
{
 "method": "POST",
 "headers": {
   "User-Agent": "testing",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
}
[2022-06-30T09:56:40.668Z] ### POST https://test.csdf/auth/login  
   
{
 "method": "POST",
 "headers": {
   "User-Agent": "testing",
   "Content-Type": "application/json"
 }
}`;

function convertToJSON(logs) {
  return logs
    .match(/\[.+\]\s\#+\s\w+\s.*\n/g) // fetch lines to parse
    .map((line) => line.split('###')[1].trim().split(' ')) //isolate method/url
    .map((log) => ({
      method: log[0],
      url: log[1],
    }));// convert array to object
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(convertToJSON(logFileContents), null, 4));
```

*if it doesn't work for your log files, just fix the regex to match your case*

Comment: this is what I'm looking for. I'm struggling on how to split it and map it into a new JSON. Thankyou!